# Stop after first find within two knowns, print, then continue searching file in perl

Tags: perl, perltk

I am writing in Perl and would like assistance.

I am trying to write a program to find "Bobby" and print the line of text with "display".

I have already written the program and have it working except one little flaw.
If "Bobby" is present multiple times under a single line with "display" in it, it will print that line multiple times. See example below for clarification.

Text file includes...

```
display ("Blue")
....
....
....
....
display ("Yellow")
....
bobby
....
bobby
bobby
....
display ("Red")
....
.... and so on
```

My current output is...

```
display ("Yellow")
display ("Yellow")
display ("Yellow")
```

It *should* be:

```
display ("Yellow")
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
while(<$AR>){
  $display = $_ if /display/;
  $output_textbox->insert("end", "$display\n") if /"bobby"/i;
}
```

I have tried a few different things but with no success.
Assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I was able to figure it out with the sample you gave me. I was inspired by it. I needed to add a simple counter into my code. It tells my second if statement to only search for bobby right after finding a line that has "display" in it. Perfect! Thanks alot. See code below for full solution.

```
 while(<$A>){

 if (/display/){
 $display = $_;
 $count=0;
 }

 if ((/"$bobby"/i) && ($count == 0)){
 $output_textbox->insert("end", "bobby\n");
 $count =1;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
if (/"bobby"/i){
   $output_textbox->insert("end", "$display\n");
   last;
}
```

The "last" will quit the loop if "bobby" is found.

Comment: That gets me close except for one thing.

Comment: Looking at my text file above, if bobby were under display ("Blue")
and under display ("Yellow"), only display ("Yellow") would be outputed with the code you provided above. I need my program to out put every line with display that contains bobby under it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two variables, just use one:

```
while (<$A> {
  $display= $_ if /display/ ;
  if ( /"$bobby"/i ) {
    $output_textbox->insert("end", "$display\n") if $display ;
    $display= undef ;
  }
}
```